# Aiomysql pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'")

Tags: mysql, database-connection, python-asyncio, python-3.9, aio-mysql

I'm new here and I'm having a problem. When running my code, an error occurs pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'"), tell me what it might be

```
import aiomysql
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def search_tel(telephone):
    conn = await aiomysql.connect(host="localhost", port="3306",
                                  user="root", password="password",
                                  db="bill", loop=loop)
    cursor = await conn.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f"SELECT TRUE FROM users WHERE telefon={telephone}")
    print(cursor.description)
    result = await cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    if result == 1:
        conn.close()
        return True
    else:
        conn.close()
        return False
tel = "000000000"
loop.run_until_complete(search_tel(telephone=tel))
```

Comment: Are you sure your connection settings are correct? Can you connect from the command line?

Comment: @dirn I am sure that everything is correct because pycharm is connected using the same data, in workbench too

Comment: Are you using "localhost" in those other places or are you using an IP address like 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @dirn Already solved the question, the problem is that the port is registered by int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the problem was that there was a problem with the port in the connection, it is written through the **int**